# UITableView checkmark imageview is set on multiple cellls

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a table view that list currencies ... I would like that only one can be selected at one time (if the user clickes an already selected cell it should remain selected)... the check mark is an uiimageview... 
Here is the code:

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[self.currencyList fetchedObjects] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CurrencyCell";

    CurrencyCell *cell = (CurrencyCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Currency *currency = [self.currencyList objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.currencyName.text = currency.name;
    cell.curencyAbreviation.text = currency.abreviation;

    if ([currency.isDefault boolValue] == YES) {
        cell.selectedCurrency.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"];
        checkedCell = indexPath;
        NSLog(@"The default currency cellfor row is :%@",currency);
        NSLog(@"the checkedcell index path is:%@",checkedCell);
    }

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // [self.delegate theSelectedCurrencyIs:[self.currencyList objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

    if (![indexPath isEqual:checkedCell]) {
    CurrencyCell *cell = (CurrencyCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.selectedCurrency.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Checkmark.png"];
    selectedCurrency = [self.currencyList objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSLog(@"The selected currency is %@",selectedCurrency);
        NSLog(@"The indexpath of the new selected currency is %@",indexPath);
    CurrencyCell *previoslySelectedCell = (CurrencyCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:checkedCell];
        NSLog(@"name of the previously selected cell %@",previoslySelectedCell.currencyName);
    previoslySelectedCell.selectedCurrency.image = nil;
        //  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath,checkedCell, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    checkedCell = indexPath;
    }
}
```

The problem is that the check-mark image is showing up in more than one selected cell.. the selected indexpath is ok... but a lot of cells look check-marked ... seems like a few on every scrolled screen

What would be the problem here?

Comment: The reason you see the checkmark sporadically, is because `UITableView` uses `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and basically recycles cells. So the cell that is checked mark and goes off the screen, and comes back on as a recycled cell has that check mark. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you should also check to make sure if that cell has check mark (as a recycled cell), and whether it should still keep it or set it to nil. Hope this clears it out for. I try to find a sample code and post it. I am sure if you look for, you find one too.

Comment: Thanks ... that was the problem...